# got a parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING'

Tags: php, sql, php-parse-error

Trying to get this solved i think it is with the quotes that is why i was trying to play with the back slash but it still not working.

the following line of code:

```
<a href='images/content/$row['image']' class='prettyPhoto zoom'></a>
```

Comment: show the entire line including the `echo`/`print`. You're probably missing some backslashes.

Comment: Try `<a href='images/content/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>' class='prettyPhoto zoom'></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Printing PHP variable value in HTML like this:

```
<a href="images/content/<?php print $row['image']; ?>" class="prettyPhoto zoom"></a>
```

Comment: here is the whole block of code - thought just that line would make sense my bad.
 echo "<li class='col1-3 landscape'> 
   <div class='project'>
        <div class='proj-img'>
       ** <a href='images/content/ " . $row['image'] . "' class='prettyPhoto zoom'></a> **
        <a href='portfolio-single.php'></a> <img src='images/content/Bimg_sample.jpg' alt=''></div>
        <div class='proj-info'>
        <h4><a href='#'> " . $row['title'] . " <br /> </a></h4>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium ...</p>
       </div> </div> </li>";

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
echo "<a href='images/content/".$row['image']."' class='prettyPhoto zoom'></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes inside single quotes.

Try removing the single quotes around "image". Like so:

```
<a href='images/content/$row[image]' class='prettyPhoto zoom'></a>
```

You can only use this if your echo statement is using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="images/content/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" class="prettyPhoto zoom"></a>
```